# Error : Cannot read property 'object' of undefined for mui-data-table npm package in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I am trying to implement a dataTable using material design concept. I came across this awesome library name [mui-data-table](https://github.com/blueyedgeek/mui-data-table) that does the work. But when I run the demo example mentioned in the documentation I get the following error on the console

```
main.js:20380 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
at Object.237.../utils/handleCustomRender (main.js:20380)
at s (main.js:1)
at main.js:1
at Object.236../lib/mui-data-table (main.js:19897)
at s (main.js:1)
at main.js:1
at Object.243../dist/index (main.js:20555)
at s (main.js:1)
at main.js:1
at Object.1.material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider (main.js:23)
```

My code in the js file is as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import {MuiDataTable} from 'mui-data-table';

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Chikwa Eligson', age: 24, location: 'Lagos', level: 'stage-1', mood: 'happy' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bamidele Johnson', age: 18, location: 'Anambra', level: 'stage-4', mood: 'anxious' },
  { id: 3, name: 'John Lee', age: 20, location: 'Abuja', level: 'stage-2', mood: 'indifferent' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Binta Pelumi', age: 22, location: 'Jos', level: 'stage-3', mood: 'sad' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Cassidy Ferangamo', age: 30, location: 'Lagos', level: 'stage-4', mood: 'angry' },
  { id: 6, name: 'Damian Swaggbag', age: 35, location: 'PortHarcourt', level: 'stage-1', mood: 'bitter' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Loveth Sweetstick', age: 20, location: 'Imo', level: 'stage-3', mood: 'happy' },
  { id: 8, name: 'Zzaz Zuzzi', age: 19, location: 'Bayelsa', level: 'stage-2', mood: 'party-mood' },
  { id: 9, name: 'Ian Sweetmouth', age: 18, location: 'Enugu', level: 'stage-4', mood: 'happy' },
  { id: 10, name: 'Elekun Bayo', age: 21, location: 'Zamfara', level: 'stage-4', mood: 'anxious' },
];

const config = {
  paginated: true,
  search: 'name',
  data: data,
  columns: [
    { property: 'id', title: 'S/N'},
    { property: 'name', title: 'Name' },
    { property: 'age', title: 'Age' },
    { property: 'location', title: 'Location' },
    { property: 'level', title: 'level' },
    { property: 'mood',title: 'Mood'},
  ]
};

export class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <MuiDataTable config={config} />
     </MuiThemeProvider>
     );
   }
 }

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

My html side of code

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong. Can somebody help me with this?

**EDIT**

My Package.json dependencies is as follows

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babelify": "^8.0.0",
"browserify": "^14.5.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-babel": "^7.0.0",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
"gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
"gulp-less": "^3.4.0",
"gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
"gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
"gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
"material-ui": "^0.20.0",
"mui-data-table": "^0.1.5",
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1",
"vinyl-source-stream": "^2.0.0",
"watchify": "^3.9.0"
},
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Yup. I ran npm install for the modules specified in the repository

Comment: @shubhamagiwal92 can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: @Lomse Add the dependencies installed in the post